# Reading dataset and extracting features in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark

Appologies for this noob question as I'm new to pyspark. I have a dataset that I have ingested into HDFS(as its huge in size). However, the dataset is not in clear text(.svm format) and I wish to apply machine learning algorithms to it.

[Link to Dataset](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/URL+Reputation)

I can read the dataset as a text file in pyspark. However, I need human readable output in the form of a matrix or something so that I can extract features from the dataset. Could someone please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
file_path = "hdfs:///path/to/file.csv"

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").getOrCreate()

df = (
        spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
            .options(header="true", inferSchema="true")
            .load(file_path)
    )
```

Comment: Hello pissall, thanks for your answer. But its still not giving me the output in clear text. Its still garbled text. Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/h71xZ2i.png

Comment: @RohanDsouza `df.show()`, and make `header="false"`. Looks like your file doesn't have column names

Comment: Thanks. Was able to get it. Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/HZCeUwn.png
Now I guess I can apply machine learning algos on it.

Comment: @RohanDsouza please select the answer to close the question if it helped